# Set AUTO_INCREMENT in all tables within a MySQL DB to the largest inserted increment value

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set `AUTO_INCREMENT` value for all tables within a database to the latest insert value?

UPDATE
For example if my table had 1000 records with increment values from 1..1000 and I have deleted last 900 records the last increment value in the field would be 100. I would like to set the AUTO_INCREMENT to the 101. And this for all tables within DB.

Comment: If the tables use the `InnoDB` engine, all you have to do is to restart the MySQL server service.

Comment: You want to reset 901-1000 after a delete  to 1-100 and reset the auto increment to 101?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to set AUTO_INCREMENT value for all tables within a database to the latest insert value?

The value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` is actually the next available value, i.e. maximum value plus 1.

If your tables use the `InnoDB` engine then all you have to do is to restart the MySQL server (not the computer but just the MySQL service).

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html#innodb-auto-increment-initialization) explains how the value of `AUTO_INCREMENT` it stored (in memory, not on disc) and restored when the service starts:

> To initialize an auto-increment counter after a server restart, InnoDB executes the equivalent of the following statement on the first insert into a table containing an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column.
>
> ```
> SELECT MAX(ai_col) FROM table_name FOR UPDATE;
> ```
>
> InnoDB increments the value retrieved by the statement and assigns it to the column and to the auto-increment counter for the table. By default, the value is incremented by `1`.

Answer (score 0):

This is automatically done.

Quoting the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the value that is currently in use. For both InnoDB and MyISAM, if the value is less than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT column, the value is reset to the current maximum AUTO_INCREMENT column value plus one.

Comment: What if select the maximum value of the increment in each table and `ALTER TABLE tablename1 AUTO_INCREMENT = $max+1`

Comment: Well, then you've increased the auto_increment value, obviously. You can increase it all you want, just not decrease it.

Comment: Well if my table had 1000 records with increment values from 1..1000 and I have deleted 900 records, I can not set the AUTO_INCREMENT to the 101?

Comment: Yes, you can? You know, what's a great way to find out? Trying it out...

Comment: @PrimozRome About your edit...have you actually read my answer? Just do a `alter table <table> auto_increment = 1` for every table and that's it. Have you any issues with this? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

AUTO_INCREMENT actually remember the last number it insert even if the data has been deleted. So if your AUTO_INCREMENT number is less than 100, you can just temporary insert a blank data with AUTO_INCREMENT number = 100 and then delete it. The next time you insert a data, it will go to 101.

You can use this query to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT number to the current highest one in the table.

ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;